# password authentication failed for user "ASUS"

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, spatial-database, loading

I'm creating table in PostgreSQL using these commands:

```
 shp2pgsql -s 32632 watershed.shp watershed > watershed.sql 
 psql -f watershed.sql cambridge
 psql -f watershed.sql cambridge
```

But I had this FATAL

> password authentication failed for user "ASUS"

How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use another user, add the parameters

```
-U myusername -W
```

`-U` specifies a username, `-W` will prompt for the password