# PostgreSQL - Creating DB, User privileges

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I created a database named "wchiba" in postgres using  :

```
create database wchiba;
```

Then I create a user :

```
create a user saifeddine with password "0000";
```

Then I grant privileges :

```
grant all on database wchiba to saifeddine;
```

Everything now is ok

But when I load a shapefile to my table I have this  problem of password

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "wchiba"
```

Also my database is wchiba not the user while the user created is saifeddine.

What's going on?

[image][image]

Does anyone know how to configure pg_hba.config

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323118/password-authentication-failed-for-user-asus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [password authentication failed for user "ASUS"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323118/password-authentication-failed-for-user-asus)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to login as a user other than the default you must tell `psql`. Please read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

```
psql -U saifeddine -d wchiba
```

will log you into Postgresql as the user saifeddine and connected to the wchiba database.

However this has nothing to do with loading a shapefile, so you probably want `shp2psql` which also takes a `-u username` option, see this [document](https://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg). In this case something like:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 watershed myschema.watershed | psql -d wchiba -U saifeddine
```

You will need to use the correct CRS for your data which may not be epsg:4326.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation bit i had this psql: FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf after writing shp2pgsql -s 32632 watershed myschema.watershed | psql -d wchiba -U saifeddine

Comment: I changed configuration of pg_hba.config from md5 to trust and it works now